# Facebook header based authentication not working

Tags: facebook, oauth, spring-social

I am using Spring Social to try to get a list of Facebook friends and their locations. From what I can see, Spring Social puts the access token into the HTTP request header as:

```
Authorization: OAuth AAAFDa6Gl4usBAJH4...
```

instead of appending it to the URL as an access_token parameter. As a result the request only returns the basic info, which does not include the location data. I can tell that the access token in the header is valid, because if I include it in a GET request manually the full dataset, including location, gets returned.

Has someone see this issue before and could let me know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that Spring Social puts the access token in the Authorization header like that (per draft 10 of the OAuth 2 specification). Now, this should probably be using the "Bearer" token format from more recent drafts, but I've been using Spring Social Facebook quite some bit over the past few days to do exactly as you are trying to do--fetch the user's friends--and it's been working fine.

Facebook's documentation seems to promote the access_token query parameter more heavily than the Authorization header, but their API supports either (always has). So, assuming that the token given is granted permission to view a user's friends, it should work.

In fact, I just double-confirmed this: First, I used the Spring Social Showcase (https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase), connected to Facebook, then clicked on the "Friends" list in the left-hand menu. It worked. I also obtained a valid access token, pointed my browser at https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends and used the Modify Headers plugin for my browser to set the Authorization header to "OAuth {my token}" and it also worked.

Have you, by any chance, tried this with the Spring Social Showcase (which is using Spring Social Facebook under the covers)? Wondering if you face the same problem there or not.

But thanks for asking about this, because it reminded me that I need to go ahead and update the header to use "Bearer" instead of "OAuth" (which I also confirmed as working).

Comment: Craig, you are absolutely correct, Facebook does accept the Authorization header. The cause of the issue appears to be on my end, due to the permissions not having been requested by the app from FB.